# PrimeFaces style sheet not loading correctly

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, frontend

I am developing a primeface project with Maven. THe primeface package is loaded in my POM file. Sometime when i get on the site the primeface style sheet is not working. Meaning I could not select an check box or do any front end interaction.

Comment: Can you please show with the code what you not able to do?

Answer (score 6):

You might have forgotten to add the <***h:head*** /> placeholder in the page that you are experiencing problems. Check it.